# AngularJS ng-disabled - Not working if input $pristine, but works if form $pristine

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to disable a materializecss button if the value of a particular input in a form is blank, but I can only successfully disable it using ng-disable if the form is $pristine, not on the input.

This works:

```
data-ng-disabled="mainDetailsForm.$pristine"
```

but this doesn't:

```
data-ng-disabled="mainDetailsForm.niNumberInput.$pristine"
```

and this doesn't:

```
data-ng-disabled="niNumberInput.$pristine"
```

-

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6qswosh8/.

-

Full HTML:

```
<form id="mainDetailsForm" name="mainDetailsForm">

<div class="row">

    <div input-field class="input-field col-xs-12 col-md-4">

        <input id="niNumberInput" name="niNumberInput" type="text" class="validate" pattern=".{9}" placeholder="National Insurance Number">

        <label for="niNumberInput" data-error="National Insurance number must be 9 characters long">National Insurance Number</label>

    </div>

    <div input-field class="input-field col-xs-12 col-md-1">

        <button data-ng-disabled="mainDetailsForm.niNumberInput.$pristine" class="btn button waves-effect"><span class="fa fa-search"></span>Verify</button>

    </div>

</div>

</form>
```

Comment: `$prisitne` is a property of `FormController` which is assigned to each`form` tag. So you can not use it with individual input elements. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the properties of individual inputs through the form you need to give the input an ng-model. The ng-model property is what binds it. I updated your jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dougefresh/6qswosh8/1/ ( I also had to get angular working properly in the fiddle).

```
    <input id="niNumberInput" name="niNumberInput" ng-model="niNumberInput" type="text" class="validate" pattern=".{9}" placeholder="National Insurance Number">
```

This small line in the docs is important "To allow styling of form as well as controls, ngModel adds these CSS classes:" It lists $dirty, $pristine, etc.. The docs specifically say they are bound to ng-model. 
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms